# Unable to find Parser.varContext

Tags: antlr4, javaparser

Trying to follow the example in definitive antlr 4 reference and stuck on page 147 where i cannot find the reference to parser.VarContext for my java grammar.** - I need to get to the ID and i cannot find VarContext, only a VarLocalContext which doesn't have the id. Did I miss something in the definitions ? I verified that the class is being generated, so its something else odd.

I've bolded the lines that get me in trouble but the VariableDeclaratorContext does exist but doesn't match what i need.

My source is below.

```
enter code here

import org.antlr.v4.runtime.tree.ParseTreeProperty;



    public class RefPhase<CatchesContext> extends JavaBaseListener {
    ParseTreeProperty<Scope> scopes;
    GlobalScope globals;
    Scope currentScope; // resolve symbols starting in this scope

    public RefPhase(GlobalScope globals, ParseTreeProperty<Scope> scopes) {
    this.scopes = scopes;
    this.globals = globals;
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public void enterFile(CatchesContext ctx) {
        currentScope = (Scope) globals;
    }

    public void enterCompilationUnit(JavaParser.CompilationUnitContext ctx) {
        currentScope = scopes.get(ctx);
    }
    public void exitCompilationUnit(JavaParser.CompilationUnitContext ctx) {
        currentScope = currentScope.getEnclosingScope();
    }

    public void enterBlock(JavaParser.BlockContext ctx) {
        currentScope = scopes.get(ctx);
    }
    public void exitBlock(JavaParser.BlockContext ctx) {
        currentScope = currentScope.getEnclosingScope();
    }

**public void exitVar(JavaParser.VariableDeclaratorContext ctx) {
    String name = ctx.ID().getSymbol().getText();**
    Symbol var = currentScope.resolve(name);
    if ( var==null ) {
        CheckSymbols.error(ctx.ID().getSymbol(), "no such variable: "+name);
    }
    if ( var instanceof FunctionSymbol ) {
        CheckSymbols.error(ctx.ID().getSymbol(), name+" is not a variable");
    }
}

public void exitCallContext(JavaParser.CatchesContext ctx) {
    // can only handle f(...) not expr(...)
    String funcName = ctx.ID().getText();
    Symbol meth = ((Object) currentScope).resolve(funcName);
    if ( meth==null ) {
        CheckSymbols.error(ctx.ID().getSymbol(), "no such function: "+funcName);
    }
    if ( meth instanceof VariableSymbol ) {
        CheckSymbols.error(ctx.ID().getSymbol(), funcName+" is not a function");
    }
 }
 }
```

Comment: The grammar isn't overly special.

Comment: I can but it keeps being deleted. Its the Java8.g4 from the web site with a mod on comments to support the channels.  The link was https://github.com/antlr/codebuff/blob/master/grammars/org/antlr/codebuff/Java8.g4